# Mapping long bit arrays to a lookup table

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

Given a set of n (n < 1000) unique bit arrays (for example c++ std::bitset class template) of length l (l > 64), which is the best mapping to store such bit arrays in a lookup table L with elements from 0 to n-1, to find them the fastest?

What I want to achieve is the following:

```
L["000010001 ... 00101010"] = 0
L["111000000 ... 01000100"] = 1
...
L["001101100 ... 01010111"] = n-1
```

The bit arrays, if converted to decimals, are not ordered.

I am currently using `std::unordered_map<std::bitset<81>, int>` and [std::unordered_map::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) but I have a feeling that there is a faster way to do it.

Comment: Where does your feeling comes from?

Comment: Given what you have explained, unordered_map<> is a good choice.  If we knew the change rate, or how many lookups your app will make, then something else might be better.

Comment: _"witch is the simplest?"_ and _"a faster way to do it"_ are generally mutually exclusive. Choose one please.

Comment: Unordered_map will generate a hash from the content of your bitset and then index using that hash. This should be relatively fast to index, but perhaps non-unique, depending on how the hash is calculated, so some linear final searches might occurr.
The hash is calculated when the items are inserted, so there is a cost of 1000 hash calculations up front, vs some log2(1000)=10 more complex comparisons  per find() call if you used say a std::set. So std::set definitely loses after 100 find()

Comment: There are 2^81 ~= 10^24 different `std::bitset<81>`, but you only have 1000. Are all of these 10^24 possible values? If not, you may reduce the range to a more managable one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` has strong advantages: it exists, has been extensively tested, and is optimized.

The only alternative I can imagine would be a binary search in an array of pairs (bit_pattern, index): requires less that 10 comparisons for an array of size < 1000.

But... needs code, tests and benchmarks...

My now grey hair tell me: *if it already exists and meet your needs, then use it*

Comment: As an aside, since we're talking about a lookup table, I can safely assume it will be written once and read many times. Would a conventional `std::map` be better here?

Comment: the `map` is the *binary search in an array of pairs* mentioned above.

Comment: Since the size is bounded, the unordered map can be initially sized to avoid the need for rehashing. I don't think a binary search is going to outperform that.

Comment: @Walter: not exactly. `std::map` is a general use binary search implementation, while I suggested a custom dedicated implementation only focused on unsigned integral keys.

Comment: In which way different from `map<unsigned,whatever>`? That you want to use an array, rather than a tree?

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer, since the code has been working for a couple of years. When I have the time I will search in the direction @midor has pointed me to.

Answer (score 2):

Depends strongly on what you care about:

- memory: probably a trie
- performance: a hashset used as sparse array (there are faster ones than `std::unordered_map` generally, and knowing the input domain often allows you to heavily optimize the hash function)
- if it is structured, possibly just a mask-operation

Generally the indexing and search of long simple sequences is extensively researched in genetics, so maybe you can find some algorithms there.

Comment: It's all about performance in my case. I'm upvoting this answer, since you gave me a good reference to start my research with (genetics, optimized hash function).

Comment: Good luck. Keep in mind that sometimes fitting into some cache can give you a bigger performance boost than reducing the number of computations.